# Xamarin form android load image after 1 second

Tags: android, image, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Xamarin Form and the Image on Android.
When I go on the page I see for some moments only the entry, and after about 1 second appear the images.
How can I fix ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YYY.Views.Basic.YYYSetup">

  <Grid Padding="5,0,5,0">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ....
      </Grid>
      <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="YYY_01.png" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ChangeDir" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_plus.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="S1Plus" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_minus.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="S1Minus" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_plus.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="S2Plus" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_minus.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="S2Minus" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_plus.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="S3Plus" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_minus.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="S3Minus" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_plus.png" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MorePYYY" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_minus.png" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="LessPYYY" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_plus.png" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MoreCYYY" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_minus.png" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="LessCYYY" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="BSW_srv_1.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="BSW_srv_2.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="BSW_srv_3.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="BSW_pYYY.png" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="BSW_cYYY.png" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=YYYVariation, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}', Mode=OneWay}" TextColor="{Binding Path=YYYColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=YYYVariation, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}', Mode=OneWay}" TextColor="{Binding Path=YYYColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=YYYVariation, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}', Mode=OneWay}" TextColor="{Binding Path=YYYColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=PYYY, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}%', Mode=OneWay}"  TextColor="{Binding Path=YYYColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=CYYY, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}%', Mode=OneWay}" TextColor="{Binding Path=YYYColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>

      </Grid>
```

...

Comment: How large is your Image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some pictures 1Kb others 2Kb.

Comment: I've faced the same problem. I haven't been able to solve it, but assumed it must be because of the format of the PNG i'm using and something must be processing the image. But I have no proof yet. I'll be watching this question with interest